# convert 16 bits signed (x2) to 32bits unsigned

Tags: type-conversion, modbus

I've got a problem with a modbus device :

The device send data in modbus protocol.

I read 4 bytes from the modbus communication that represent a pressure value

I have to convert theses 4 bytes in a unsigned 32bits integer.

There is the modbus documentation :

`COMBINING 16bit REGISTERS TO 32bit VALUE
Pressure registers 2 & 3 in SENSOR INPUT REGISTER MAP of this guide are stored as u32 (UNSIGNED 32bit INTEGER)
You can calculate pressure manually :
1) Determine what display you have - if register values are positive skip to step 3.
2) Convert negative register 2 & 3 values from Signed to Unsigned (note: 65536 = 216 ):
(reg 2 value) + 65536* = 35464 ; (reg 3 value) + 65536 = 1
3) Shift register #3 as this is the upper 16 bits: 65536 * (converted reg 3 value) = 65536
4) Put two 16bit numbers together: (converted reg 2 value) + (converted reg 3 value) = 35464 + 65536 = 101000 Pa
Pressure information is then 101000 Pascal.`

I don't find it very clear... For exemple, we don't have the 4 bytes that gives this calcul.

So, if anybody has a formula to convert my bytes into a 32bits unsigned int it could be very helpful

Comment: Do you have some example input and output values?  I have used val=struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('<HH', int1, int2)) with modbus to combine two 16bit registers but not sure if this would apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read your bytes in some kind of type representation (hex, dec, bin, oct...)

let's assume you're receiving the following bytes frame:

in hex:

```
0x00, 0x06, 0x68, 0xA0
```

in bin:

```
0000 0000, 0000 0110, 0110 1000, 1010 0000
```

all of these are different representation of the same 4 bytes values.

Another thing that you should know is the bytes position (endianess):

If you're frame is transmitted in *big endian*, you're going to read the bytes in the order that you have them ( so `0x00, 0x06, 0x68, 0xA0` is correct).

If the frame is transmitted in *little endian*, you need to perform the following operation:

Switch the first 2 bytes with the last 2:

```
0x68, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x06
```

and then switch the position between the first and the second byte and the third and the fourth byte:

```
0xA0, 0x68, 0x06, 0x00
```

so if your frame is in *little endian*, the correct frame will be `0xA0, 0x68, 0x06, 0x00`.

If you don't know the endianess, assume it's in *big endian*.

Now you simply have to 'put' your values togheter:

```
0x00, 0x06, 0x68, 0xA0 will become 0x000668A0
```

or

```
0000 0000, 0000 0110, 0110 1000, 1010 0000 will become 00000000000001100110100010100000
```

Once you have your hex or bin, you can [convert your bin to an integer](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/how-binary-to-decimal.html) or [convert your hex to an integer](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/numHexToDec/)

[Here](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) you can find an interesting tool for converting HEX to float, unit32, int32, int16 in all endianess.

**TL;DR**

if you can use python, you should use [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

frame = [0x00, 0x06, 0x68, 0xA0] # or [0, 6, 104, 160] in dec or [0b00000000, 0b00000110, 0b01101000, 0b10100000] in bin

print struct.unpack('>L', ''.join(map(chr, frame)))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved, I had to reorganize the bytes like : [byte0, byte1, byte2, byte3] as byte2 << 24 + byte3 << 16 + byte0 << 8 + byte1. Thanks a lot

Comment: This means that your bytes are sent in little endian